# Jersey: Error when a class has both JAX-RS and JAX-WS annotations

Tags: java, jax-ws, jersey, jax-rs

Using Jersey 1.7, JAX-WS 2.2.3, Tomcat 6.0.30 and the following method declaration prevents Jersey servlet to start:

```
@POST
@Produces("text/plain")
public void postIt(@WebParam(name = "paramOne") final String paramOne, 
                   final String paramTwo) {
    // ...
}
```

The generated exception is:

```
SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public 
        java.lang.String com.sun.jersey.issue.MyResource.postIt(
          java.lang.String,java.lang.String) at parameter at index 0
SEVERE: Method, public void 
        com.sun.jersey.issue.MyResource.postIt(
          java.lang.String,java.lang.String), 
        annotated with POST of resource, 
          class com.sun.jersey.issue.MyResource, 
          is not recognized as valid resource method.
```

If the `@WebParam` annotation is removed, it all works fine.

Now, please have in mind that I am not trying to work with mere strings, rather, I am migrating complicated Objects that got marshalled/unmarshalled using SOAP to RESTful services, but I must provide both interfaces for a while, without breaking the previous WASDs. The method is just a minimalistic scenario.

Has any of you any idea of the status of this? Has it been fixed? Suggestions?

Comment: I've never seen the `WebParam` annotation in RESTful web services (even if I've just discovered its presence in jax-rs package). What are you trying to do? Are params coming from the query, the path, the header? Can you provide the HTTP request asked to the server?

Comment: The `WebParam` annotation comes from jax-ws. What I am trying to achieve is to have the same method servicing SOAP, JSON, XML, plain text and HTML. For SOAP I am using Sun's implementation of jax-ws, for the rest I am using Jersey... BTW, if you use `WebParam` you get a WSDL where instead of parameter names such as `arg0`, `arg1`, you get parameters with a _pretty_ name.

Comment: After some debugging, I figured out that the two parameters lacked JAX-RS annotations, therefore, both would be read from the request body. JAX-RS 1.1 (section 3.3.2.1) specifies that "`Resource methods MUST NOT have more than one parameter that is not annotated with one of the above listed annotations.`", so my bad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification is clear on this. Section 3.3.2.1 tells us that:

> Resource methods MUST NOT have more
>   than one parameter that is not
>   annotated with one of the above listed
>   annotations.

The *above listed annotations* are the JAX-RS parameter annotations: `@QueryParam`, `@MatrixParam`, etc.

There is, however, a Jersey specific way to solve this problem. Using `InjectableProvider`. So, a method that defines two non-JAX-RS parameters:

```
@POST
public void postIt(@CustomInjectable final Customer customer, 
                   final Transaction transaction) {
  // ...
}
```

Of course, we have to code the annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
public @interface CustomInjectable {
}
```

An implementation of `InjectableProvider` that knows how to provide `Customer`s:

```
import com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.InjectableProvider;
import com.sun.jersey.api.model.Parameter;

@Provider
public class CustomerInjectableProvider implements 
             InjectableProvider<CustomInjectable, Parameter> {

  // you can use @Context variables, as in any Provider/Resource
  @Context 
  private Request request;

  public ComponentScope getScope() {
    // ComponentScope.Singleton, Request or Undefined
  }

  public Injectable getInjectable(ComponentContext i, 
                                  CustomInjectable annotation, 
                                  Parameter param) {
    Injectable injectable = null;
    if (Customer.getClass().isAssignableFrom(param.getParameterClass()) {
      injectable =  getInjectable();
    }
    return injectable;
  }

  private Injectable getInjectable() {
    return new Injectable<Customer>() {
        public Customer getValue() {
          // parse the customer from request... or session... or whatever...    
        }
     };
  }
}
```

But, Jersey considers only the last annotation (see [JERSEY-ISSUE-731](http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-731)), so be careful.

And, a more portable way (if you *do* care about that, anyway):

```
// simple bean
public class CustomerWithTransaction {
  private Customer customer;
  private Transaction transaction;

  // getters and setters
}
```

Then change the method to:

```
@POST
public void postIt(CustomerWithTransaction customerWithTransaction) {
  // ...
}
```

Then create your own `MessageBodyReader` for `CustomerWithTransaction`, where you can also access any context variables (request, headers, etc.).